# Charles Schwab shows Ebay's PE as 21. Is that a mistake or a different way of calculating?

Tags: stocks, investing, price-earnings-ratio

Using Charles Schwab data the TTM earnings for Ebay is 2.5B + 2.668B + 2.368B + 2.868B = 10.404B

Shares outstanding is 626M

So 10.404 B / 626 M = 15.9 EPS.

So PE is 58 / 15 = 3.86. How is Charles Schwab calculating the PE to be 21? I see they also are calculating the EPS to be 3.4. I've seen a couple other websites that are showing the same thing. Which is correct? Or are they both correct depending how it is calculated. They are just such different numbers I don't understand how they both could be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers you use to get ~$10B annual "earnings" appear to be *revenue*, not earnings. (Earnings are revenue minus expenses.)

Comment: Okay thank you that makes sense.  I see Yahoo Finance has a PE of around 3.2.  I wonder if they use Revenue to calc P/E.

Comment: @Mwspencer P/E should never use revenue (that would be price to sales or P/S). There is an anomaly in *some* sources reporting eBay's earnings for Q2 2021 alone as more than $10B or $15 per share. I don't know the reason (glitch or definitional technicality), but that seems to explain the low P/E quoted.

Comment: Ebay had a very anomalous 2Q2021 net income due to discontinued operations  according to Yahoo - without digging any further it's possible that either that number is wrong or that Schwab is ignoring the part that's from discontinued operations (which would make sense).